# How can I declare the type in localStorage?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I can't getItem from localStorage the error is "Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
var localStorage: Storage" and "Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'."

```
const getLocalStorage = () => {
  let groceryList = localStorage.getItem('grocery-list');
  if (groceryList) {
    return (groceryList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('grocery-list')));`here is the error      here is the error in localStorage and 'grocery-list'`
  } else {
    return [];
  }
};

function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState(getLocalStorage());

 useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('grocery-list', JSON.stringify(list));
  }, [list]);`here I set item to localStorage`
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JSON.parse` method requires its first argument to be of type `string`, not `null`.

The problematic code is `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('grocery-list'))`.
The type of `localStorage.getItem('grocery-list')` could be `string` or `null` and thus you get the error.

I'd refactor your `getLocalStorage` function code to:

```
const getLocalStorage = () => {
  const groceryList = localStorage.getItem('grocery-list');

  if (groceryList) {
    return JSON.parse(groceryList);
  }

  return [];
};
```

Note the `if` statement: we first check the `groceryList` is not null and this is why inside we can work with `string` type.

Answer (score 1):

localstorage.getItem returns a string or undefined. By adding your if check, you guard against that. However because you call JSON.parse on another call to localstorage instead of the variable you defined the guard does no longer work. Instead do this

```
const getLocalStorage = () => {
  let groceryList = localStorage.getItem('grocery-list');
  if (groceryList) {
    return JSON.parse(groceryList);
  } else {
    return [];
  }
};
```